# What is the war summary addendum of Mahabharata?

Tags: vyasa, itihasa, mahabharata

I remember reading a small Sanskrit work which was supposed to be an addendum of Mahabharata, which summarizes the war and gives dates according to Hindu calendar.

I can't recall where I read it or it's name.

What is the war summary addendum of Mahabharata? Please post a link

Comment: Harivamsha is the only known appendix to Mahabahrata. Whichever else is not part and parcle of main epic.

Comment: No it's not part of the main epic, but a traditional addendum which summarizes the war

Comment: As I said Harivamsha is  traditional appendix or supplement to the Mahabharata. What do you mean by  " traditional" here?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Its very short, like 2 pages, I remember reading its told at the emd of Mahabharata war traditionally to summarize it.